# AdventureWorks SalesOrderDetail query performs scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm using the `Adventureworks` database to learn a little more about SQL Server execution plan.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT ProductID, SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderDetailID = 10;
```

I get back 1 record but the plan shows a SCAN:

[image]

I thought it would be a SEEK since the table has an index on the `SalesOrderDetailsID`, there is a key based on `SalesOrderId` and `SalesOrderDetailId`:

[image]

Running these queries, both show SEEK:

```
SELECT ProductID, SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderDetailId = 10
  AND SalesOrderID = 43659;

SELECT ProductID, SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderID = 43659;
```

[image]

Why would `SalesOrderId` perform a `SEEK`, but `SalesOrderDetailId` not?

I thought since they were both part of the primary key, either would be `SEEK`. Or if one was not neither would be unless the query used both.

Comment: Because `SalesOrderDetailId` isn't the leading column n the key. It has to try to find `SalesOrderDetailId = 10` but for _every_ `SalesOrderID` value. It's cheaper to scan. Imagine trying to find all the `FirstName = John` in the phone book, instead of `LastName = Smith` (or even `LastName = Smith AND FirstName = John`).

Comment: (As an aside, in this specific case and knowing that detail ID is actually unique, it is curious why you would have a Detail ID without knowing the parent Order ID, and if that is a common in your real world scenario, you should consider an index in the opposite direction - e.g. one that _leads_ on the detail column, but also includes all the other columns the query needs.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand great example, the query was just something I was playing around with to see how the execute plan would work when using either of the keys.